# How to get the length of an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array and I want to append some new items on click, but first of all I need to get the length of array in order to add the item on right place. This is how array looks like:

```
"parent": [{
   "child": {}, 
   "child2": {},
   ...
 }];
```

Array needs to look exactly like this and it's empty on page load. I want to insert values in child elements for example:

```
"parent": [{
    "child": {
       "0": 1,
       "1": 1,
       "2": 1
     },
     ...
 }];
```

First of all on start I cannot get length of child array :(

**Note** that array must look exactly like this and child elements should be in array order from 0 to n.

Everytime I ask for child length I get "undefined" as response. Even if I put manually value ex. "child": {"0": "1", "1": "1"} i got undefined as child length.

Comment: Currently the children are objects, not arrays. Is there a reason you did that? objects don't have a `.length` property, nor a dependable order.

Comment: @NicholasTower Yeah, the API is requesting that format only, so I need to append somehow elements into child but in order from 0 to n elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have a length, you will need to use `Object.key` like in example:

```js
let array = {
  "parent": [{
    "child": {
      "0": 1,
      "1": 1,
      "2": 1
    }
  }]
};


console.log(Object.keys(array.parent[0].child).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an array, but an object whose properties are `"0"`, `"N"`...

Either refactor this to use an actual array or do this:

```
const length = Object.keys (o.parent[0].child).length
```

...which may include these and other own object's properties, so it's not reliable for your purpose...

There's no definitive solution if you don't want to use arrays.

### Approach to make this more reliable

If your input has these objects instead of arrays, you might want to convert them to arrays, and then operate on them!

Here's a code snippet which defines `objectToArray` and produces an array for keys that can be converted into numbers:

```js
const o = { '0': 'hello', '1': 'world', '2': '!!!' }

const objectToArray = o => Object.entries (o)
                            .filter (([key]) => !isNaN (key))
                            .reduce ((array, [key, value]) => 
                                (array[Number (key)] = value, array),
                                []
                             )

const output = objectToArray (o)

console.log (output)
```